# How do I request fund in coinbase api?

Tags: php, coinbase-api

Hi I am trying to use coinbase api in php.api implementation working fine, I can check balance, creat new address all this are working fine.But facing problem on request bitcoin. I am following [coinbase official api librery](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-php) , accroding documention on mentioned link request fund usage code is

```
use Coinbase\Wallet\Enum\CurrencyCode;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Money;

$transaction = Transaction::request([
    'amount'      => new Money(8, CurrencyCode::USD),
    'description' => 'Burrito'
]);

$client->createAccountTransaction($transaction);
```

And I used exactly what they said, but I am getting error, bellow is my code

```
<?php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

use Coinbase\Wallet\Client;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Configuration;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Enum\CurrencyCode;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Money;

$apiKey='xxxxxxx';
$apiSecret='xxxxxxx';
$configuration = Configuration::apiKey($apiKey, $apiSecret);
$client = Client::create($configuration);

$transaction = Transaction::request([
    'amount'      => new Money(8, CurrencyCode::USD),
    'description' => 'Burrito'
]);
$client->createAccountTransaction($transaction);
echo json_encode($client->decodeLastResponse());
?>
```

And error is

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Coinbase\Wallet\Client::createAccountTransaction() must be an instance
>   of Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Account, instance of
>   Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction given, called in
>   /file_path/file.php on line 19 and defined in
>   /library_path /vendor/coinbase/coinbase/src/Client.php:359 Stack
>   trace: #0 /file_path/file.php(19):
>   Coinbase\Wallet\Client->createAccountTransaction(Object(Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction))
>
> ## 1 {main} thrown in /library_path /vendor/coinbase/coinbase/src/Client.php on line 359

### update:

---

I tried by adding specific account parameter

```
$account=$client->getPrimaryAccount();
$transaction = Transaction::request([
        'amount'      => new Money(8, CurrencyCode::USD),
        'description' => 'Burrito'
    ]);

  $client->createAccountTransaction($account,$transaction);
```

And then I got error exception `To peremeter missing`  so I added to parameter

```
Transaction::request([
            'to'=>'test@mail.com',
            'amount'      => new Money(8, CurrencyCode::USD),
            'description' => 'Burrito'
        ]);
```

And now error is

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction::setTo() must be an instance of
>   Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Resource, string given, called in
>   /home/exhakduz/api/vendor/coinbase/coinbase/src/Resource/Resource.php
>   on line 70 and defined in /library_path
>   /vendor/coinbase/coinbase/src/Resource/Transaction.php:199 Stack
>   trace: #0 /library_path
>   /vendor/coinbase/coinbase/src/Resource/Resource.php(70):
>   Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction->setTo('test@mail.com') #1
>   /library_path /vendor/coinbase/coinbase/src/Resource/Resource.php(25):
>   Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Resource->updateAttributes(Array) #2
>   /library_path
>   /vendor/coinbase/coinbase/src/Resource/Transaction.php(119):
>   Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Resource->__construct('transaction', Array)
>
> ## 3 /library_path /vendor/coinbase/coinbase/src/Resource/Transaction.php(114):
>
> Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction->__construct('request', Array) #4
>   /library_path /receive.php(20):
>   Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction::request(Ar in /library_path
>   /vendor/coinbase/coinbase/src/Resource/Transaction.php on line 199

Answer (score 0):

Your call should also reference `$account`:

```php
$account = $client->getPrimaryAccount();

$transaction = Transaction::request([
    'amount'      => new Money(8, CurrencyCode::USD),
    'description' => 'Burrito'
]);

$client->createAccountTransaction($account, $transaction);
```

Comment: I asked about receive/request bitcoin,not send bitcoin

Comment: @SahidulIslam, documentation has a bug. You need to specify account as a first parameter in your code

Comment: Tnx for your solution, I used $account peremeter and then I got "parameter missing 'to'" so I added an email  "to" paremeter   and then erroe is

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction::setTo() must be an instance of Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Resource, string given, called in /library_path /vendor/coinbase/coinbase/src/Resource/Resource.php on line 70 and defined in /library_path /vendor/coinbase/coinbase/src/Resource/Transaction.php:199 Stack trace: #0 /library_path /vendor/coinbase/coinbase/src/Resource/Resource.php(70): Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction->setTo('email@mail.com') #1 /path/vendor/coinbase/coinbase/src/Resource/Resource....

Comment: Post updated,plz take a look for better understanding

Comment: @SahidulIslam `'to' => new Email('test@test.com')`

Comment: After update Email class was missing, then I added use xxx\xxx\Email; and now error is missing parameter 'type', I tried by adding 'type'=>'payment'/receive et still same, what is type parameter?

Comment: the type param would be `request`. I have a more current question in ruby where I am getting the same thing even with the type `request` in my request to the api

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$client->createAccountTransaction($account, $transaction);
Transaction::request([
        'toEmail'=>'test@mail.com',
        'amount'      => new Money(8, CurrencyCode::USD),
        'description' => 'Burrito'
    ]);
$client->createAccountTransaction($account, $transaction);
```